# Iframe should fit entire screen in mobile

Tags: php, html, css, iframe, responsive-design

Here is my code for the iframe:

```
<?php
echo '
    <div id="travel_div" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
        <iframe src="' .content_url(). '/ic-content/tab-search" class="ic_frame_search" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" seamless ></iframe>
    </div>
    ';
?>
```

When I view it on phone, the iframe is stuck in a set box and doesn't move down the page.
Here's the page: https://guysgonegolfing.com/travel/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used  `scrolling="no"` which means it wont allow Scroll page . Try to use the follwing code ...

```
  <?php
    echo '
        <div id="travel_div" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
            <iframe src="' .content_url(). '/ic-content/tab-search" 
              class="ic_frame_search" frameborder="0" 
              style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;" 
              width="100%" height="100%" seamless ></iframe>
        </div>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Done that! It looks good. Thanks! However, I want it to not have the scroll bar and it should fit the entire screen when viewed on mobile screen. No scrolling within the iframe. How do I do that?